# Fix for "Incorrect Resource URL" message

Tags: wordpress, error, php

In my Wordpress installation of CiviCRM I have had a persisting System Status:Error message since version 4.7.28 which was still present despite upgrade to 4.7.31.  This appeared to be a false-positive as CiviCRM was working well.
The Resource URL was correct and I could not get rid of the error until I upgraded PHP from version 5.6 to version 7.0, and the error message disappeared!!

Answer (score 1):

The error disappeared after upgrading php to version 7.0